# Does the iPhone 8/8+/X Require Metal for a Mag Mount?

Tags: iphone

Older iPhones required a metal plate be secured to the phone to work with a magnetic mount.  With wireless charging, does the iPhone 8/8+/X require a metal plate to work with a magnetic mount, or does the wireless charging circuitry provide enough attachment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All those iPhones require the metal plate.

We have tested this on 2 iPhone 8 Plus and neither of them were magnetic enough to hold to the mount.  I would expect the iPhone X to be similar.

Comment: With a metal plate is a form of a cover for the iPhone, you could have some issues with wireless charging